# script xcode "Copy items if necessary"

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to script / automate adding am file to a project so you get the same as moving a file manually?

Like when you get asked "Copy items if necessary", when moving a file into a project.

Comment: That dialog is completely available to Accessibility so if you really had to you could just use System Events to drive the whole process. :(

Comment: You probably know that you can add a file to a target with the AppleScript `add` command, but that doesn't solve the part of the problem you're asking about, namely the options in that dialog.